# readFile function not working on second iteration with different argument - c++

Tags: c++, function, ifstream

I've written a readFile function for a project I'm working on. I call it once, load in a file and read in it's contents - works fine

However, when I try to load it a second time, attempting to change the file name - it loads it in, saves it to a static string 'path' that I access in a different function - but then the function is not printing the data

***The question is***, how do I change the file name, and read it in successfully on the second iteration? The part that has me stumped is that it works once, but not twice

Ive attempted to use cin.ignore(); cin.clear(); cin.sync() on the second iteration of fileName function - but none of them allow a separate file to be read successfully.

Minimum Reproducible Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static string path;
string opt;
void readFile();
int fileName();

void menu() { // put in while loop - while True
    cout << "----------------------" << endl;
    cout << "R(ead) -" << "Read File" << endl;
    cout << "F(ile) -" << "Set Filename" << endl;
    cout << "\nPlease select from the above options" << endl;
    cin >> opt;
    cout << "\nInput entered: " << opt << endl;
    if (opt == "R") {
        readFile();
    }
    if (opt == "F") {
        fileName();
    }
}

void readFile() { // doing this twice
    ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open(path);
    if (!readFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Could not read file" << endl;
    }
    string str;

    int i = 0;
    while (getline(readFile, str))
    {
        if (str[0] != '/')
        {
            cout << "DEBUG: Line is - " << str << endl;
        }
    }
    readFile.clear();
    readFile.close();
    menu();
}

int fileName() {
    cout << "File path: ";
    if (path != "") {
        cin.ignore();
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
    }
    getline(cin, path);
    ifstream file(path.c_str());
    if (!file) {
        cout << "Error while opening the file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "(File loaded)" << endl;
    cout << "Path contains: " << path << endl;
    file.clear();
    file.close();
    menu();
}

int main()
{
    fileName();
}
```

Sample text, saved as txt file and read in using path:
Data1.txt

```
// standard test file
123,Frodo inc,2006, lyons,"1,021,000.16",0.0,
U2123,Sam Inc,2006, lyons,"21,600.00",13.10,123
A721,Merry Inc,2604, Kingston,"21,600.10",103.00,
U2122,Pippin Inc,2612, reid,"21,600.00",0
U1123,Huckelberry corp,2612, Turner,"21,600.00",13.10,
```

Data2.txt

```
7101003,Mike,23 boinig road,2615,48000,12000,0
7201003,Jane Philips,29 boinig cresent,2616,47000,12000,0
7301003,Philip Jane,23 bong road,2615,49000,000,0
7401004,Peta,23 bong bong road,2615,148000,19000,0
7101205,Abdulla,23 Station st,2615,80000,21000,0
```

The problem comes from reading in one, and trying to read in the other after the first has been executed.

1. Enter Filename
2. Hit Readfile
3. Return to menu, hit Set Filename
4. Change to Data2.txt
5. Readfile again. Not working

My tutor told me "That's not how functions work in c++" but didn't elaborate further, and is unavailable for contact.

Comment: How are you calling the functions? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why do you think you need to use a static object?

Comment: You're not clearing your input stream properly.

Comment: I thought I needed to use a static to retain the value of path while swapping between functions - I thought they were destroyed at the end of that function

Comment: @Nina i suspected that, and tried to spam clear it using each different method, but it wouldn't clear

Comment: This is what classes are for, in C++: they have members that any class method can access, no static objects are required.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik would you recommend I make an class filename instead of function, create an object for the first entry, and a new object for the second?

Would I be able to overwrite the object on each call of the declaration if I was to put it into the loop?

Comment: Why does a function called `readFile` call `menu`? Shouldn't the `readFile` function just read a file?

Comment: It calls menu to navigate back to menu, but I should just put it in a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, do not use global variables. The path variable should be passed as a parameter, not kept as a global variable altered between function calls, as this leads to many side effects and is the source of countless bugs. See the following refactoring:

```
void menu() { // put in while loop - while True
while(true)
{
    //Keep this as a local variable!
    std::string opt;
    std::string filename;
    cout << "----------------------\n";
    cout << "R(ead) -" << "Read File\n";
    cout << "F(ile) -" << "Set Filename\n";
    cout << "\nPlease select from the above options\n";
    cin >> opt;
    cout << "\nInput entered: " << opt << '\n';
    if (opt == "R") {
        readFile(filename);
    }
    if (opt == "F") {
        filename = getFileName();
    }
}
}

void readFile(const std::string & filename) { 
    ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open(filename);
    if (!readFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Could not read file " << filename << '\n';
    }
    string str;

    int i = 0;
    while (getline(readFile, str))
    {
        if (str[0] != '/')
        {
            cout << "DEBUG: Line is - " << str << '\n';
        }
    }
    readFile.close();
    //just return to get back to menu
    return;
}

std::string getFileName() {
    cout << "File path: ";
    std::string path;
    getline(cin, path);
    ifstream file(path.c_str());
    if (!file) {
        cout << "Error while opening the file" << '\n';
        //Instead of returning an error code use an exception preferably
    }
    cout << "(File loaded)" << '\n';
    cout << "Path contains: " << path << '\n';
    file.close();
    return path;
}
```

Other notes:
Ideally, do input in output in just one function, not all three as it gets confusing exactly what each function is responsible for.

If you want something to hold a file and print the contents, you can use an class.

The file is checked if it is openable twice, not really any reason to do this just delegate that responsibility to one function.

One of the best things about C++ is RAII and deterministic lifecycles for objects and primitives - use it!! Do not give everything a long life with global variables - use smart parameters and return values instead.

Comment: Problem was inadvertently solved by adding it to the while loop you outlined here - so thank you for that. I will take the rest on board